# JDBC Postgresql CopyManager unable to copy lines of data/text without delimiters in CSV

Tags: java, postgresql, csv

Please I am working with a directory containing more than 1000 log files and these files have been cleaned and saved as csv files. For some reason which I don't know, some of the files do not have the csv delimiter ',' attached to some lines of the csv file. So during processing in java with CopyManager.copyIn(), it fails to proceed whenever it ecounters a line without the delimiter ',' as well as newlines. Please find below the file snippet of the csv file and my sample code. Please kindly help me resolve this error/problem, thus whenever there is no delimiter or missing values/empty strings or new line corresponding the db table column names or not, it stops/throws an error. Thanks in advance.

CSV File Snippet:

```
1.1.2.0,sentence,2011,Apr,22,Fr,1,0.046  ,0, 0
01.03.04.05,synonyms,2011,Apr,22,Fr,1,0.012  ,0, 0
09.08.07.06 
0.08.07.06,sentence,2011
```

From the csv file above,each column corresponds to a field name of a table in the postgres db, i.e:
response(ip_address,service,year,month_of_year,day_of_month,day_of_week,hour_of_week,response_time,coord_x, coord_y)

Java code snippet:

```
int characters_to_insert_at_once =1000
public static void insertFile()
{
CopyManager copyManager = new CopyManager((BaseConnection) conn);

for(File file : dir.listFiles())
{
long record_count = copyManager.copyIn("COPY        response(ip_address,service,year,month_of_year,day_of_month,day_of_week,
hour_of_week,response_time,coord_x, coord_y) FROM STDIN DELIMITER ','",
new FileInputStream(file), characters_to_insert_at_once);
}
}
```

Comment: You can't use  `copy` for such a file.

Comment: what do you suggest I use for this kind of file? That will have the same same processing speed as COPY

Comment: You need to fix the file so that it has the same number of columns in every line. Otherwise you can not use `copy`

Comment: Is not only one file with missing values, there are more 100 files with missing values. what other method should I use instead of COPY?

Comment: If you can put those files on the server (where Postgres runs) you can use the `text_array` FDW: http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/251-File-FDW-Family-Part-2-file_textarray_fdw-Foreign-Data-Wrapper.html